# Finding zeroes of $x^3-5x^2+11x+17$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, roots

I'm trying to find all the zeros of $x^3-5x^2+11x+17$. I figured the possible zeros as being  +/- 1, +/- 17$. The book says that -1 is supposed to be a factor, but I tried dividing the polynomial by -1 with synthetic division and it ended up not being a zero. I know I have to get it down to a degree of 2 to get the other answer, but from what I've seen I need to first find that other zero and use the result of the synth division which will put it at a degree of two, or something like that. SO I'm not really sure what to do with this now.

Comment: $(1 + x) (17 - 6 x + x^2)$ I suspect you tried $(x-1)$, which is not a root. Hopefully, you know the quadratic equation to continue.

Comment: Thanks guys. Was just doing something really stupid. I think I've been this way too long... :/

Comment: $x^3+5x^2+11x+7 = (x+1)(x^2+4x+7)$.

Comment: Just a suggestion: it will probably help if you try to make sure you get terminology correct: $-1$ is a root of the polynomial, not a factor, while $x-(-1)$, that is, $x+1$, is a factor.  Dividing the polynomial by $-1$ is very easy:$$x^3-5x^2+11x+17=(-1)(-x^3+5x^2-11x-17)\ ,$$but of course this is not what you want.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the identities of Viète to avoid the hazards of polynomial division.

The sum of the roots is $5$, so the sum of the missing roots is $6$.

The product of the roots is $-17$, so the product of the missing roots is $17$.

It follows that the missing roots are solutions of $x^2-6x+17=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Let $f(x)=x^3-5x^2+11x+17$.

$f(-1)=0\Rightarrow (x+1)|f(x)$.

Divide, and get a quadratic factor. I'm sure you'll be able to find the other two roots then.